# How to create a middleware to respond to all static file requests on express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware, static-files

This is express recommendation on how to serve static files:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Actually, this is how I'm implementing it, and it works:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"../static")));
```

But the problem is that some static files on my URL are not **real static** files, as they are built on the fly to serve the request.

For example: `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`

So right now, this is how I'm dealing with this:

```
app.get("/robots.txt", robotTxt_handler);
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"../static")));
```

Those specific files routes come before the `app.use(express.static())`, hence they are responded with those specific handlers.

But I'd like to separate that logic into an `express.router()` in a different file.

Something like:

**staticRouter.ts**

```
export const staticRouter = express.router();

// HANDLE STATIC ROUTES THE SAME WAY I DESCRIBED ABOVE
```

So on my main file I would do:

**index.ts**

```
app.use("/xxx.xxx", staticRouter);
```

So all requests made to static file routes on my app should be handled by my `staticRouter` middleware.

But my question is, how can I represent all possible static routes into my `app.use("/xxx.xxx", ...)` ?

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at npm [express-robots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-robots) either to see how that author did it, or just to use it.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is not how to generate the `robots.txt` file. I just need a way to extract all the `static` files logic to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you can pass the `path` property as a RegExp.

So the following code should work, but you need to be extra careful with what chars are allowed in your static files.

[Link to Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DOVw8t/2)

```
app.use(/^(\/[\w-]+)+(\.[\w-]+)+$/i, (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send("THIS IS A STATIC FILE ROUTE");
});
```

This regex allows `a-z`, `0-9`, `-` and `_` to be container in folders and file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in order limit your express middleware, worked for me.

```
if (req.originalUrl === '/site/') {
  logger.log('info', `Req-Time: ${date}`);
  next();
} else {
  next();
}
```